# Object reference not set to an instance of an object with no error line

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, stack-trace

I know that it is a wrong type of question but I have been tired...

I have sent the published files to the customer and now they say they have an error. They printed the error for me. It is something like this:

[image]

It is an intranet application and does not have any problem in my local and because of security reason I can not remote to their server.

What is your suggestions...

Any help...

Comment: Its a null reference exception

Comment: Next time, please show your work as a text, not as an image..

Comment: you have a problem with employeeID

Comment: And show source code, not just the exception.

Comment: If you're tired, get some sleep. There is no better remedy.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means some object is null and you try to access one of it's properties or methods.
The exception is thrown from `ReportSection` method from `SiteMaster` class, you can put your `.pdb` files beside your dll to get the line number too.

Comment: You mean I should copy that to the server that contains published files?

Comment: Yes, copy them into `BIN` folder on the server , or if you don't have access ask them to copy that

Answer (score 0):

If want error line to be printed in your Error stack trace than you have to include .pdb file.

Pdb file generally contains debugging information used by the debugger.

So you have to put .pdb file along with .dll file to get more debugging information.